# Perl: difficulties with regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have problem with making regular expression on perl, may be someone can help me.
Input strings:

```
bss/216476/29/52/9___\000243477___agt-1319.jpg
bss/216476/29/52/9___\000243477___agt-1319_1.jpg
bss/216476/29/52/9___\000243477___agt-1319_2.jpg
```

What i expect to get:

29 52 9 1319 or 29 52 9 1319 0

29 52 9 1319 1

29 52 9 1319 2

My Regex works only with last 2 strings:

```
/\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d+).*-(\d+)_(\d{1})/
```

As you can see in first line there is no picture number such _0.jpg and here is a problem.
I had tried to make regex like

```
/\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d+).*-((\d+)_(\d{1}))|(\d+)/
```

but looks like i'm wrong.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non capturing group `(?:...)` and a `?` to make it optional:

```
/\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d+).*-(\d+)(?:_(\d{1}))?/
```

It also can clean up your regex some if you use a different delimiter in cases where you need to include a slash.  Additionally, you can use the `/x` modifier so you can include spacing for readability:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (m{ / (\d{2}) / (\d{2}) / (\d+) .*- (\d+) (?:_(\d{1}))? }x) {
        print join(" ", map {$_//''} ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)), "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
bss/216476/29/52/9___\000243477___agt-1319.jpg
bss/216476/29/52/9___\000243477___agt-1319_1.jpg
bss/216476/29/52/9___\000243477___agt-1319_2.jpg
```

Outputs:

```
29 52 9 1319
29 52 9 1319 1
29 52 9 1319 2
```